# Validate Python TypedDict at runtime

Tags: django-rest-framework, mypy, python-typing, typeddict

I'm working in a Python 3.8+ Django/Rest-Framework environment enforcing types in new code but built on a lot of untyped legacy code and data.  We are using TypedDicts extensively for ensuring that data we are generating passes to our TypeScript front-end with the proper data type.

MyPy/PyCharm/etc. does a great job of checking that our new code spits out data that conforms, but we want to test that the output of our many RestSerializers/ModelSerializers fits the TypeDict.  If I have a serializer and typed dict like:

```py
class PersonSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['first', 'last']

class PersonData(TypedDict):
    first: str
    last: str
    email: str
```

and then run code like:

```py
person_dict: PersonData = PersonSerializer(Person.objects.first()).data
```

Static type checkers don't be able to figure out that `person_dict` is missing the required `email` key, because (by design of PEP-589) it is just a normal `dict`.  But I can write something like:

```py
annotations = PersonData.__annotations__
for k in annotations:
    assert k in person_dict  # or something more complex.
    assert isinstance(person_dict[k], annotations[k])
```

and it will find that `email` is missing from the data of the serializer.  This is well and good in this case, where I don't have any changes introduced by `from __future__ import annotations` (not sure if this would break it), and all my type annotations are bare types.  But if `PersonData` were defined like:

```
class PersonData(TypedDict):
    email: Optional[str]
    affiliations: Union[List[str], Dict[int, str]]
```

then `isinstance` is not good enough to check if the data passes (since "Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks").

What I'm wondering is if there already exists a callable function/method (in mypy or another checker) that would allow me to validate a TypedDict (or even a single variable, since I can iterate a dict myself) against an annotation and see if it validates?

I'm not concerned about speed, etc., since the point of this is to check all our data/methods/functions once and then remove the checks later once we're happy that our current data validates.

Comment: [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#rejected-alternatives) links to one possible solution: [typing_inspect](https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect). You could also map the input to dataclasses.

Comment: Unfortunately, typing_inspect is focused on looking at the types themselves, not whether data conforms to a type.

Comment: +1 to using dataclasses - there are already some powerful validation libraries for converting dicts to dataclasses and vice versa (I'm a big fan of `dacite` for simple deserialization, and you can also check out `marshmallow` if you want to do heavier validation)

Comment: Thank you @sara -- I appreciate it.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution I found works using pydantic.

### Solution for pydantic v2

```py
import pydantic

from pydantic import TypeAdapter, ValidationError
from typing_extensions import TypedDict # Required by pydantic for python < 3.12

class SomeDict(TypedDict):
    val: int
    name: str
    
SomeDictValidator = TypeAdapter(SomeDict)

# this could be a valid/invalid declaration
obj: SomeDict = {
    'val': 12,
    'name': 'John',
}

# validate with pydantic
try:
    obj = SomeDictValidator.validate_python(obj)
except ValidationError as exc: 
    print(f"ERROR: Invalid schema: {exc}")
```

see [`TypeAdapter`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev-v2/usage/type_adapter/) documentation for more information.

### Solution for pydantic v1

```py
from typing import cast, TypedDict 

import pydantic

class SomeDict(TypedDict):
    val: int
    name: str

# this could be a valid/invalid declaration
obj: SomeDict = {
    'val': 12,
    'name': 'John',
}

# validate with pydantic
try:
    obj = cast(SomeDict, pydantic.create_model_from_typeddict(SomeDict)(**obj).dict())
except pydantic.ValidationError as exc: 
    print(f"ERROR: Invalid schema: {exc}")
```

EDIT: When type checking this, it currently returns an error, but works as expected. See here: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/3008

Comment: have you got this working with nested TypedDicts? i.e. let's say name is defined like `name: SomeOtherDict` where SomeOtherDict is also a TypedDict?

Comment: Actually, pydantic will not throw an error with `obj {'val': '12', 'name': 'John'}` (see https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/578) except for when you use pydantic's own strict types.

Comment: Adding to @MoritzMakowski information, fixing the check above would need to change the class definition to: 

```class SomeDict(TypedDict):    val: pydantic.StrictInt
  name: pydantic.StrictStr```

Comment: `pydantic.create_model_from_typeddict` has been [removed in pydantic v2](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev-v2/migration/#removed-in-pydantic-v2).

Comment: What if you want to throw in the case there's an extra key?   Ex: `{'val': 12, 'name': 'John', 'unwanted_key': 'should throw!'}`.  I'm asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77165374/runtime-checking-for-extra-keys-in-typeddict) too.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at https://pypi.org/project/strongtyping/. This may help.

In the docs you can find this example:

```
from typing import List, TypedDict

from strongtyping.strong_typing import match_class_typing


@match_class_typing
class SalesSummary(TypedDict):
    sales: int
    country: str
    product_codes: List[str]

# works like expected
SalesSummary({"sales": 10, "country": "Foo", "product_codes": ["1", "2", "3"]})

# will raise a TypeMisMatch
SalesSummary({"sales": "Foo", "country": 10, "product_codes": [1, 2, 3]})
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of a hack, but you can check two types using mypy command line `-c` options. Just wrap it in a python function:

```
import subprocess

def is_assignable(type_to, type_from) -> bool:
    """
    Returns true if `type_from` can be assigned to `type_to`,
    e. g. type_to := type_from

    Example:
    >>> is_assignable(bool, str) 
    False
    >>> from typing import *
    >>> is_assignable(Union[List[str], Dict[int, str]], List[str])
    True
    """
    code = "\n".join((
        f"import typing",
        f"type_to: {type_to}",
        f"type_from: {type_from}",
        f"type_to = type_from",
    ))
    return subprocess.call(("mypy", "-c", code)) == 0
```

Comment: Thank you!  it *IS* a hack, but it is a hack that works, so worth the bounty!  How to get the types from actual data is still a little bit of a mystery, BUT I think that I should be able do something like a repr(data) and try to make the assignment.

Comment: I was not, unfortunately, able to get this to work with actual data, where I had instance data as one of the types.

Comment: ... But this doesn't solve the problem, does it? Isn't OP asking about checking whether the model matches the class at runtime, e.g. has all required fields and possibly not additional fields? Doesn't this just check two types? And launching a process to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def validate(typ: Any, instance: Any) -> bool:
    for property_name, property_type in typ.__annotations__.items():
        value = instance.get(property_name, None)
        if value is None:
            # Check for missing keys
            print(f"Missing key: {property_name}")
            return False
        elif property_type not in (int, float, bool, str):
            # check if property_type is object (e.g. not a primitive)
            result = validate(property_type, value)
            if result is False:
                return False
        elif not isinstance(value, property_type):
            # Check for type equality
            print(f"Wrong type: {property_name}. Expected {property_type}, got {type(value)}")
            return False
    return True
```

And then test some object, e.g. one that was passed to your REST endpoint:

```
class MySubModel(TypedDict):
    subfield: bool


class MyModel(TypedDict):
    first: str
    last: str
    email: str
    sub: MySubModel

m = {
    'email': 'JohnDoeAtDoeishDotCom',
    'first': 'John'
}
assert validate(MyModel, m) is False
```

This one prints the first error and returns bool, you could change that to exceptions, possibly with all the missing keys. You could also extend it to fail on additional keys than defined by the model.

Comment: probably need a Sentinel instead of None, since None can be a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

I like your solution!. In order to avoid iteration fixes for some user, I added some code to your solution :D

```
def validate_custom_typed_dict(instance: Any, custom_typed_dict:TypedDict) -> bool|Exception:
    key_errors = []
    type_errors = []
    for property_name, type_ in my_typed_dict.__annotations__.items():
        value = instance.get(property_name, None)
        if value is None:
            # Check for missing keys
            key_errors.append(f"\t- Missing property: '{property_name}' \n")
        elif type_ not in (int, float, bool, str):
            # check if type is object (e.g. not a primitive)
            result = validate_custom_typed_dict(type_, value)
            if result is False:
                type_errors.append(f"\t- '{property_name}' expected {type_}, got {type(value)}\n")
        elif not isinstance(value, type_):
            # Check for type equality
            type_errors.append(f"\t- '{property_name}' expected {type_}, got {type(value)}\n")

    if len(key_errors) > 0 or len(type_errors) > 0:
        error_message = f'\n{"".join(key_errors)}{"".join(type_errors)}'
        raise Exception(error_message)
    
    return True
```

some console output:

```
Exception: 
        - Missing property: 'Combined_cycle' 
        - Missing property: 'Solar_PV' 
        - Missing property: 'Hydro' 
        - 'timestamp' expected <class 'str'>, got <class 'int'>
        - 'Diesel_engines' expected <class 'float'>, got <class 'int'>
```

Comment: What are you referring to with *I like **your** solution*? Please hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `typing.get_type_hints` function which returns a dict from a `TypeDict` (tested under python 3.8):

```
from typing import TypedDict, get_type_hints

def checkdict(value: object, typedict: type) -> None:
    """
    Raise a TypeError if value does not check the TypeDict.
    :param value: the value to check
    :param typedict: the TypeDict type
    """
    if not isinstance(value, dict):
        raise TypeError(f'Value must be a dict not a: {type(value).__name__}')
    d = get_type_hints(typedict)
    diff = d.keys() ^ value.keys()
    if diff: # must have the same fields
        raise TypeError(f"Invalid dict fields: {' '.join(diff)}")
    for k, v in get_type_hints(typedict).items():
        if not isinstance(value[k], v): # must have same types
            raise TypeError(
                f"Invalid type: '{k}' should be {v.__name__} "
                f"but is {type(value[k]).__name__}"
            )

class TargetDict(TypedDict):
    name: str
    integer: int

obj: dict = {
    'name': 'John',
    'integer': '3',
}

checkdict(
    obj, TargetDict
)  # TypeError: Invalid type: 'integer' should be int but is str
```