# Runtime checking for extra keys in TypedDict

Tags: python, pydantic, typeddict

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68483666/2223706) tells how to validated a TypedDict at runtime, but it won't catch the case of an extra key being present.

For example, this doesn't throw.  How can I make it throw?

```py
from typing import Any, TypeVar

from pydantic import TypeAdapter
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

T = TypeVar('T')

def runtime_check_typed_dict(TypedDictClass: type[T], object_: Any) -> T:
    TypedDictValidator = TypeAdapter(TypedDictClass)
    return TypedDictValidator.validate_python(object_, strict=True)


class MyThing(TypedDict):
    key: str

obj_: Any = {'key': 'stuff', 'extra': 'this should throw!'}

runtime_check_typed_dict(MyThing, obj_)
```

Comment: I didn't get your doubt well but i think the idea is that. We have to check if the dictionary has the type as required and if there is extra key in the dictionary, we have to remove it. Am I getting you right? If I am then, I will give you the code.

Comment: Yup, and I'm trying to do it natively with Pydantic (or know if it's not possible).  I'd like to avoid writing my own code that checks for extra keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My Answer

- You should set `extra='forbid'`.
- (Documentation) How to config `typing_extensions.TypedDict` for `pydantic`: https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/usage/strict_mode/#dataclasses-and-typeddict
- Here's the example for both `typing_extensions.TypedDict` and `pydantic.BaseModel`.

### My Example

```py
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Any, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, TypeAdapter, ValidationError
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

T = TypeVar('T')


def runtime_check_typed_dict(TypedDictClass: type[T], object_: Any) -> T:
    TypedDictValidator = TypeAdapter(TypedDictClass)
    return TypedDictValidator.validate_python(object_, strict=True)


class MyThing(TypedDict):
    key: str


obj_ = {'key': 'stuff', 'extra': 'this should throw!'}


### 1: TypedDict


# https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/usage/strict_mode/#dataclasses-and-typeddict
MyThing.__pydantic_config__ = ConfigDict(extra='forbid')
try:
    runtime_check_typed_dict(MyThing, obj_)
except ValidationError as exc:
    pprint(exc.errors())
    # > [{'input': 'this should throw!',
    # >   'loc': ('extra',),
    # >   'msg': 'Extra inputs are not permitted',
    # >   'type': 'extra_forbidden',
    # >   'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/extra_forbidden'}]


### 2: BaseModel


class MyThing2(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='forbid')
    key: str


try:
    runtime_check_typed_dict(MyThing2, obj_)
except ValidationError as exc:
    pprint(exc.errors())
    # >[{'input': 'this should throw!',
    # >  'loc': ('extra',),
    # >  'msg': 'Extra inputs are not permitted',
    # >  'type': 'extra_forbidden',
    # >  'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/extra_forbidden'}]
```