TypedDict from typing_extensions is not working
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

class Person(TypedDict):
    name: str
    age: int
    is_employee: bool
    
person: Person = {
    "name": "Baber",
    "age": "ten year",  #as i assagin "string" datatype to age instead of "int" but it does not show any error?
    "is_employee": True 
}

print(person['age'])

I want this function to show me error due to wrong assignment to integer variable.

from typing import TypedDict

@JonasPalačionis it is also in _extensions, for older versions of Python: https://typing-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#typing_extensions.TypedDict.

Good to know, thank you.

When and where are you expecting the error? For example, mypy will absolutely refuse it: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=feb8cc59074671b4e4d21fe0d501f74d. But if you're expecting Python itself to error at runtime, read the boxout at the top of https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html.

Related: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665336/validate-python-typeddict-at-runtime, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555006/how-to-type-hint-type-check-a-dictionary-at-runtime-for-an-arbitrary-number.

As explained in this answer , "python won't raise type errors at runtime based on type hints".
mypy could be used to statically type check your program.
Note that this approach works in such a straightforward example, but could fail when types are not explicitly declared with types annotations.
For instance, using mypy on this program would pass:
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

def return_str():
    return "test"

class Person(TypedDict):
    name: str
    age: int
    is_employee: bool
    
person: Person = {
    "name": "Baber",
    "age": return_str(),
    "is_employee": True 
}

print(person['age'])

An alternative to the solution of mypy, would be to use the module pydantic:
import pydantic

def return_str():
    return "test"

class Person(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    is_employee: bool
    
person = Person.model_validate({
    "name": "Baber",
    "age": return_str(),  # error
    "is_employee": True 
})

print(person.age)

Pydantic will perform runtime checks, even when type annotations are not given, and will return an error of the form:

return cls.pydantic_validator.validate_python(
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for
Person age   Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string
as an integer [type=int_parsing, input_value='test', input_type=str]

Note that runtime checks have to reach the error to report it. Hence, you should respect the fail-fast principle and check data as soon as possible. This has to be used when static type checkers as mypy cannot verify the types of data retrieved from other files or APIs for instance.

yeah it worked! thank you

if you want to catch type errors like assigning a string to an integer field, you need to use a type checker like mypy because python won't raise type errors at runtime based on type hints. You need tools like mypy for static type checking.
first install mypy
pip install mypy

then run
  mypy filename.py

then you'll start seeing the errors like this
filename.py:8: error: Incompatible types (expression has type "str", TypedDict item "age" has type "int")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

